# why the defunct process is using CPU?

Tags: linux

I am having some confusion with defunct process. That is, Why the defunct process is using CPU. I absorbed the CPU time utilization of the defunct process in top command. Sometimes, The defunct process is taking more than 55 CPU time. But,As per some of the documentation,the defunct process should not use CPU.

```
  PID   TID CLS RTPRIO  NI PRI PSR %CPU STAT WCHAN           COMMAND                                                                                                   
15304 15304 TS       -   0  19   0  0.6 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
15494 15494 TS       -   0  19   7  0.4 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
17075 17075 TS       -   0  19   5  0.5 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
17659 17659 TS       -   0  19   2  0.6 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
18118 18118 TS       -   0  19   7  0.8 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
18388 18388 TS       -   0  19   4  1.1 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
18520 18520 TS       -   0  19   3  0.7 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
18864 18864 TS       -   0  19   3  0.7 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
19291 19291 TS       -   0  19   5  1.1 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
19479 19479 TS       -   0  19   3  1.0 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
19544 19544 TS       -   0  19   1  1.3 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
19806 19806 TS       -   0  19   6  1.1 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
19809 19809 TS       -   0  19   4  2.0 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
20056 20056 TS       -   0  19   7  1.3 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
20577 20577 TS       -   0  19   5  2.2 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
22239 22239 TS       -   0  19   4  6.9 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
22246 22246 TS       -   0  19   3  2.2 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
22269 22269 TS       -   0  19   7  2.1 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
23337 23337 TS       -   0  19   5  3.2 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
23950 23950 TS       -   0  19   4  7.2 Z    -              My.pl <defunct>
```

Can you clarify me why the defunct process is using CPU?

Comment: 1. `top` is not the best tool for such cases. Use `ps` a couple of times with e.g. a 5 minute interval and see if the CPU time of the process in question has increased. 2. Please paste the output of `ps` for the process in question...

Comment: What kind of process is it? What is the executable? How exactly is it "defunct"? Can you `strace` it? Give much more details to get help....

Comment: It is a perl executable file.

Comment: @sat: Not all Perl executables are defunct :-)

Comment: I added the ps command output with CPU time.

Comment: why -1? May I know the reason.

Comment: @choroba there are those that would say that `perl` is defunct... ;-)